# Get Text of Certain Tag after Tag with Certain Text HTML in Android with JSoup

Tags: android, html, jsoup

I want to Get Text of Certain Tag after Tag with Certain Text from HTML with JSoup like this :

```
<td>AAA</td>
<td>1111</td>


<td>BBB</td>
<td>2222</td>
```

I want to print 1111 if I select AAA, or print 2222 if I select BBB

I Have try this, but nothing printed in text field :

```
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            // Connect to the web site
            Document document = Jsoup.connect(url).get();
            // Using Elements to get the Meta data
            Elements description = document
                    .select("td [value=AAA] td");
            // Locate the content attribute

            desc= description.text();

        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Set description into TextView
        TextView txtdesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.desctxt);
        txtdesc.setText(desc);
        mProgressDialog.dismiss();
    }
```

Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your selector would select the all `td`s *within* a `td` that has an attribute named "value" with the value "AAA".

Instead, you must match the content of td tags. There is a pseudo selector `matchesOwn` available for that purpose. (own means, only match the direct text of the element, not that of any children).

Then, advance to the next sibling element (or, if there can be another element following before the td of interest, query again using "td" as the selector).

Try

```
Element description = document.select("td:matchesOwn("AAA")).first().nextElementSibling();
```

Beware, the parameter of the `matchesOwn` pseudo selector is interpreted as a regex.